# How do I download SQL Server 2012 Express?

Tags: download, sql-server-2012

I feel like an idiot asking this question, but I can't seem to find the magic combination. (Or maybe Microsoft's website is broken. I'm not sure which.) Anyway, here's what I'm trying.

1. Open [SQL server Home Page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/default.aspx) On [Microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx)
2. Click "Editions".
3. Click "Express Edition" in the little box that appears.
4. On the page that loads, I click the "Download SQL Server 2012 Express" button.
5. On the modal that pops up, I pick one and click its download button. (It doesn't matter which. I get the same result for the few I've tried.)
6. A new page opens and presents me with 64 and 32 bit options and language drop downs for each.
7. I select English in the 64-bit drop down.
8. I click Download.
9. The following page about downloading Windows Server 2012 opens and no file is downloaded:

   > [TN Download Windows Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh670538.aspx)

Is there something I'm missing? Surely, I don't need to have Windows Server 2012 to install SQL Server 2012. I've tried a couple different browsers.

Comment: Your original links actually do work I have tested them.  For some reason you are being directed to `...\betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPMS/enus/default.aspx` which would indicate to me this was based on you being directed from Technet Evaluation website instead of the main product page for SQL Server.  Its odd you were not directed to link I was able to find.

Comment: @Ramhound Odd with a capital O. Hm. Took another look. It looks like the download buttons themselves point to those "betaexperience" URLs when I hover over them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it works. Here is the 64Bit ENU Link (without tools):

> Care Download Center : [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express 64-bit](http://care.dlservice.microsoft.com/download/5/2/9/529fef7b-2efb-439e-a2d1-a1533227cd69/SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe?lcid=1033&cprod=sqldenexppost32)

Here is an additional link:

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35575)

Comment: ...It opens a Java download manager, on a Microsoft website? Not that it's impossible. It just seems... unlikely.

Comment: yes, MS often provides a JAVA downloadmanager for browsers like Firefox and Chrome. The activex version only works with IE.

Comment: Well, thanks. I don't know why I was getting directed to a page about a Server 2012 download.

Comment: @jpmc26 - The domain is Microsoft.com I don't understand your concern.  There is no way that cannot be Microsoft's website nor is there any possibility it cannot be the file you want.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not a security expert, but I do know a bit about man in the middle attacks. Since it's not over SSL/TLS, something could be feeding me their own data; no? It's just... weird. I've never run into a download manager for anything from MS before.

Comment: @jpmc26 - What you describe is not possible.  The domain is microsoft.com there is no possible way data being transferred on that domain can come from ANY source except Microsoft's server.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Microsoft uses a download experince for a great deal of things dealing with Technet, MSDN, and Dreamspark.

Comment: Thanks for that second link. It's not obvious by any means, but all the different editions are available there (if you can figure out what the heck the file names mean). While searching around for the Tools Only version not knowing it was there the whole time, I ran across the service pack, too: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35575

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Internet Explorer to download, If I try to download with Chrome then I get the same "no response". With Microsoft Internet Explorer it started to download immediately.